# My function does work when I click the button (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've been working on this for a few days and I can't figure out why I can't show my function when I click on the button. Here's my code...

```
     <div class="dayOfYear" style="display:none" >{{ toDayOfYear(day.date) }}</div>
      <script>

        function showingChange(){
          let ID = document.getElementById('dayOfYear')
          if (ID.style.display === 'none') {
             let x = ID.style.display === 'block'
            return x
          }
        }

      </script>
```

Comment: There's no button in this code block you posted.

Comment: why are you using script tag

Comment: also agree with @Chellappan, your question is marked 'Angular' and 'Typescript' but you're embedding Javascript in your html using `<script>` tags. This is very bad practice.

Comment: @ChristianScillitoe <button id="theButton" onclick="showingChange()">Day of Year</button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular delete all the script tag from the html, you should write the function's code in ts file:

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="showingChange()"></button>
```

**TS**

```
showingChange(){
    let ID = document.getElementById('dayOfYear')
    if (ID.style.display === 'none') {
        let x = ID.style.display === 'block'
            return x
    }
}
```

**Edit (Angular method):**

**HTML**

```
    <button (click)="showingChange()"></button>
    <div class="dayOfYear" [ngStyle]="{'display':show == true ? 'block' : 'none' }" >{{ toDayOfYear(day.date) }}</div>
```

**TS**

```
public show: boolean = false;
showingChange(){
    this.show = true;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn´t access the dom over the document object... better way is to make a class variable and show/hide the element with the *ngIf directive

Comment: I agree with Mateusz, but this will work. Also, unrelated but he is getting by id of day of year but it's actually the class

Comment: @MateuszKlimentowicz thanks, i change the answer and add a more practical way.